# How to Change the Maximum Length of the `labelText` in a Flutter `TextFormField`?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, textfield

Usually, I change the `labelText` in a `TextFormField` using the decoration parameter:

```dart
TextFormField(
  ...
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'min 8 characters allowed',
  ),
),
```

However, since some texts are a bit long, Flutter will replace the ending with the ellipsis (`…` or `Unicode 2026`) character. I think there's still some space available in the `labelText` though, and, thus, would like to show the complete text anyway.

[image: <code>TextFormField</code> with ellipsis replacing the end of the "long" <code>labelText</code>]

I've tried to look around where the ellipsis are put in, but haven't been able to find it. I haven't been able to find a parameter that would change this for the `InputDecoration` class either. The `TextField` source was *not* very helpful also.

Comment: If you go into the [Flutter source repo on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) and look for `2026`, you will find [this line](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fed6ce17f8e17b1e6e8e2f84229e48af458c80af/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart#L272), which will probably be very helpful.

Comment: I've created [Flutter Issue #53166](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53166) about this topic.